# Limit of integrals on disks

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral, density-function

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}_+$. Lebesgue differentiation theorem states that normalized limit of integrals of $f$ by sets shrink to x is equal to $f(x)$. I need analogue of that theorem for the following situation.

Let $S_\varepsilon(t) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \colon t-\varepsilon \leq |x| \leq t+\varepsilon \}$, $\gamma(t) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \colon |x|=t \}$. Then (I guess) when some conditions hold
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{|S_\varepsilon(t)|}\int_{S_\varepsilon(t)}f(x)\, dx = \int_{\gamma(t)} f(x) \, dx.
$$

Does anyone know such results?

Comment: But $γ(t)$ is already a zero-measure set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Maybe there needs another form of integrals in this situation.

Comment: Yes, if $d=2$ the right integral must be line integral.

Comment: @AlexKoz Not "line integral", quite - actually "(normalized) integral with respect to arc length".